# pass function into JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, function, stringify

I need to pass the handleUpdateHours function in my payload below, how can I do

```
const handleUpdateHours = async () => {
            firestore()
                .collection('Providers')
                .doc(req.body.providerId)
                .collection('ServiceHistory')
                .doc(req.body.serviceProviderId)
                .update({
                    additionalHours: Number(req.body.hours)
                });

            firestore()
                .collection('Clients')
                .doc(req.body.clientId)
                .collection('ServiceHistory')
                .doc(req.body.serviceClientId)
                .update({
                    additionalHours: Number(req.body.hours)
                });
        }
```

> payload:

**I was trying what's with // commented on the payload but it didn't work.**

**he is not adding my function to the object I do not receive any error but also does not add the function**

```
const payload = {
            tokens: [clientFcmToken],
            data: {
                // notification: {
                //         typeObj: () => handleUpdateHours(),
                //         data: {
                //             type: () => handleUpdateHours(),
                //         }
                //     },
                notifee: JSON.stringify({
                    title: 'O Helper está solicitando horas adicionais ao serviço',
                    body: 'Você deseja aceitar?',
                    data: {
                        type: '() => handleUpdateHours()',
                    },
                    // notification: {
                    //     typeObj: () => handleUpdateHours(),
                    //     data: {
                    //         type: () => handleUpdateHours(),
                    //     }
                    // },
                    android: {
                        channelId: 'default',
                        actions: [
                            {
                                title: 'Aceitar',
                                pressAction: {
                                    id: 'acceptHours',
                                    type: () => handleUpdateHours(),
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                title: 'Recusar',
                                pressAction: {
                                    id: 'refuseHours',
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                }),
            },
        }
```

Comment: valid JSON format does not accept fields that are functions, have you tried writing your own custom replacer function?

Comment: Why do you submit(?) functions?

Comment: I need to call this function on front end event, and I have access to payload @Andreas